# Verificar se todos os valores de uma array fazem parte de outra

Tags: php

Eu estou trabalhando com este código

```
if(in_array($_GET['a'], array('value1', 'value2', 'value3'))) {
    [...]
}
```

Ele serve para conferir se `$_GET['a']` esta dentro da array.

Estou tentando passar os valores `value1,value2,value3` em `$_GET['a']` para que fosse realizado a "verificação" destes valores na array, se todos existirem ele executa meu código => `[...]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar [**array_diff**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-diff.php) para calcular a diferença e considerar o array igual ou não.

Sendo o seu *inputA* uma string, basta usar `explode` para transformar em array e comparar os itens em `arrays`. Note que a ordem do array **não** influencia o resultado. Coloquei um exemplo no [**Ideone**](http://ideone.com/qOe2Ua) com 2 casos.

Quando houver diferença, o output será um array com **chave e valor** `array[3]=>value999`, caso sejam iguais, mesmo em ordem diferente, o output será um **array vazio**.

```
$inputA = explode( ', ' , 'value1, value2, value3, value999' );
$arrays = array( 'value3', 'value1', 'value2' );
print_r( array_diff( $inputA , $arrays ) );
```

---

> [*DOC*](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-diff.php):
>   `array_diff( array $array1 , array $array2 [, array $ ... ] )`
>
> Retorna um **array** contendo todas as entradas de array1 que não estão presentes em algum dos outros arrays.

Comment: Boa, neste caso é bem mais simples do que minha sugestão

Comment: @bfavaretto, apenas outra forma :)

Answer (score 3):

Se entendi a pergunta corretamente, e se você tem mesmo arrays iguais nas duas pontas, pode utilizar o operador `==`. Ele vai retornar `true` quando ambas arrays tiverem as mesmas chaves e valores:

```
array('a' => 10, 'b' => 20) == array('b' => 20, 'a' => 10)
```

Nesse exemplo com chaves explícitas, a ordem não é importante. Mas como no seu exemplo as chaves são implícitas (numéricas), será preciso ordenar as arrays primeiro. O exemplo ainda considera que a entrava chega como string separada por vírgulas, como você comentou:

```
$entrada = sort(explode($_GET['a']));
$referencia = sort(array('value1', 'value2', 'value3'))
if($entrada == $referencia) ...
```

<sup>[Veja um teste](http://ideone.com/CDYmvr)</sup>

Nesse caso, pode usar também `===`, que exige que os valores nas arrays tenham as mesmas chaves e tipos, na mesma ordem (essas duas últimas condições não se aplicam ao `==`).

Já o `in_array` quando recebe uma array como primeiro parâmetro, verifica se **qualquer um** dos valores dela está contido na outra, e não se **todos** estão contidos nela (ver [exemplo no manual](http://php.net/in_array#example-5138)).

---

**Referência: [Manual do PHP - *Array operators*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php)**

Comment: Saudações! o valor que `$_GET['a']` recebe é separado por virgulas, nao é oficialmente uma array.

Comment: Bom, nesse caso basta fazer `explode(',', $_GET['a'])` para transformar em array

Comment: Vejamos, usando os operadores, como citou, ele ira igualar independente da ordem dos valores (eu penso que nao) porem sou receptivo a receber os valores em ordens diferentes e aleatorias.

Comment: Hm, no caso de arrays com chaves implícitas a ordem sempre faz diferença. Vou editar a resposta.

Comment: Estou no aguardo...

Comment: Editei, @user3163662. Veja se agora resolve.

Comment: não seria `array_values`ao invés de `sort`, visto que sorte só aceita valores passados por referência?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Para usar o `==` os valores e as respectivas chaves precisam ser iguais, por isso usei `sort`. O `array_values` também garantiria isso?

Comment: @bfavaretto, `array_values`retorna apenas os valores do array, reordenados numericamente. No seu exemplo, a maneira que `sort` foi utilizada geraria alguns erros, pois essa função só aceita valores **passsados por referência**

Comment: @WallaceMaxters O `array_values` parece mesmo servir nesse caso, mas não achei no manual nada que diga que ela retorna os valores ordenados (embora eu tenha visto isso nos meus testes). Será que é garantido? Sobre o `sort` que usei, não vejo problema. Sim, a array é passada por referência e ordenada *in-place*, mas isso não necessariamente seria um problema para o restante do código do autor da pergunta. Mas reconheço que pode interferir dependendo do que ele quiser fazer com essas arrays depois.